# creating a simple SOAP server

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a Java project which talks to a SOAP server. I need to debug my application on my local machine. I do not want my application to get connected to the main SOAP server. I need to have a fake SOAP web server to which my application gets connected.

I want it to be as simple as possible. So, I want the server to returns a specific response for any request it receives! Is there any way by which I can reach my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to build a real server for testing/debuging your code.
you can use a Mock.

This way:

- you don't change your real code,
- the testing code is reusable,
- you don't need to implement logic, just tell it what is the expected call results
- you test only your own class (there might be bugs in the soap server)

The most popular mocking framework is Mockito.

It can be as simple as:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@Test
public void test1()  {
        //  create mock
        MyClass test = mock(MyClass.class);

        // define return value for method createSoapCall()
        when(test.createSoapCall()).thenReturn(43);

        // use mock in test....
        assertEquals(test.createSoapCall(), 43);
}
```

tutorial: 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

official site:
http://site.mockito.org/